# Filter and get Data From Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an app where I have to get products from the firestore by the name of a category. I am new to flutter and don't know how to do that. Here is my firebase layout.

[image: Firestore Data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to filter out docs with their types or properties in firebase. In your case, the firebase firestore structure is not clearly visible. But you can try out the below code or can make changes to that code. If you want continuous data you can make the stream function for that, else you can make it future. Check out the below code for reference.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getProductsByCategories(
      String categoryName) {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot = firestore
        .collection('products')
        .where('category', arrayContains: categoryName)
        .snapshots();

    return snapshot;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay Got it! I have to call this function using streamBuilder right? or is there any other way?

Comment: There are many ways, you can use stream builder as well. If you are using state management then you can try it using bloc, provider, etc. It's all up to you.